# Swift - Animation Direction

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have having a nightmare with a simple problem. On my app I have clouds moving in the background (currently from left to right).

However with the background they need to be right to left.

Eddited for the more of the page code below. Hopefully this will be easier to work out where I have gone wrong.

```
@IBOutlet var cloud1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var cloud2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var cloud3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var cloud4: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    cloud1.alpha = 0.0
    cloud2.alpha = 0.0
    cloud3.alpha = 0.0
    cloud4.alpha = 0.0

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.1,
                   options: [],
                   animations: {
                    self.cloud1.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.1,
                   options: [],
                   animations: {
                    self.cloud2.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.1,
                   options: [],
                   animations: {
                    self.cloud3.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.1,
                   options: [],
                   animations: {
                    self.cloud4.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: nil)

    animateTheClouds(cloud: cloud1)
    animateTheClouds(cloud: cloud2)
    animateTheClouds(cloud: cloud3)
    animateTheClouds(cloud: cloud4)

}

func animateTheClouds(cloud : UIImageView) {
    let cloudMovingSpeed = 60.0/view.frame.size.width
    let duration = (view.frame.size.width - cloud.frame.origin.x) * cloudMovingSpeed
    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration), delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        // Animate the origin to be off the left side of the screen.
        cloud.frame.origin.x = cloud.frame.size.width
    }, completion: {_ in
        // Reset back to the right edge of the screen
        cloud.frame.origin.x = -self.view.frame.size.width
        self.animateTheClouds(cloud: cloud)
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to move them from right to left then you simply need to change the starting and ending x origin.

```
func animateTheClouds(cloud : UIImageView) {
    let cloudMovingSpeed = 60.0/view.frame.size.width
    let duration = (cloud.frame.origin.x + cloud.frame.size.width) * cloudMovingSpeed
    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration), delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        // Animate the origin to be off the left side of the screen.
        cloud.frame.origin.x = -cloud.frame.size.width
    }, completion: {_ in
        // Reset back to the right edge of the screen
        cloud.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
        self.animateTheClouds(cloud: cloud)
    })
```

Also make sure the initial x origin is set to `self.view.frame.size.width`.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. That was exactly as I originally tried. The issue with this is that the 4 clouds now move all at different speeds rather than together. Once a cloud reaches the left hand side of the screen it then ramps up to a speed that is quite literally faster than the eye can keep up.

Comment: See my update. The calculation for duration also need to be updated.

Comment: This is closer to what I was looking for. The result gives me the 4 clouds appearing at their different start locations, and moving at different speeds still so meet at the left hand screen at the same time. The animation then starts with them all at the right hand side together overlaying each other moving to the left as one block

Comment: One more update for the duration calculation. Give that a try.